Finding ceiling fans (and other things) that aren't made of plastic
I went to a big box store and bought some ceiling fans, only to discover that the swing joints are made of plastic instead of metal. These joints rub together constantly when the fan is running, and them being made of plastic means the fan isn't going to last very long. I estimate it'll wear out right when I get too old to do this shit anymore. The cosmetic portions of the fans are made of metal, because making them out of plastic isn't necessary to ensure fast obsolescence.
It seems that everything sold at those big box stores is made of plastic, and there isn't anyplace else that I'm aware of where I'd be able to find things that aren't (although I hired some plumbers who were able to get an all-metal toilet valve from a shop that only sells to licensed plumbers).
Is it even possible to buy well-made components without having every single license out there (plumber, electrician, etc)?

Many stores have excellent quality fans. Like everything, you get what you pay for.  Maybe expand your budget.

First, most shops that cater to professionals also sell to the public. There's one in a large city near me that has a huge sign outside that says "no public, we only sell to licensed plumbers", but that's about it. Everyone else sells directly to the public. Now, what you can't expect is for the people behind the counter to be nice to you when you want to be tutored for free on how to install a $5 part, when there's a plumber right behind you with a $5,000 order and things to do. When I go to suppliers that are outside of my trade, I make sure to go with a list of parts, and only come with a few questions that can't be answered with a good Internet search.
The issue of plastic and/or cheap parts is more complex than you might think. For example, the plastic part that you think will break soon might just last the lifetime of the house: designs change, and usually for the better. When people tell me "they don't make houses like they used to", I always reply "and that's a good thing."
There is also no reliable way -- other than experience -- to tell apart good quality manufacturers from bad ones. It used to be that Made in Taiwan was a sign of bad quality, then it became a sign of good quality, and then I purchased a Taiwanese bandsaw that is just not well made. German tools are a crapshot these days. And then manufacturers change suppliers all the time, meaning that you can buy the same tool a couple years later and get a completely different quality.
We are just now in a time in which you cannot just use country of origin, name brand, or even your experience a few years back to estimate quality. You need to know what are the features that make a tool (or fan) good, test it and then reward the manufacturer with your purchase.

Also your location can determine what they can sell to Joe or a professional.  Years ago was changing/adding a control on my furnace.  I could not get that control for the furnace without a license, but could get the same part for something else.  It did depend on what you ask for and what it was for.

When I called a plumber with a problem caused by a plastic part bought at Lowe's (which sells nothing but plastic versions of that part), he told me that the metal part he brought with him came from a vendor that only sold to licensed plumbers. I've never actually found any stores that sell good parts. I assume that the pros know where to find pro-only vendors, and I'd find out only if I was in the trade. Everything at Lowe's and Home Depot is cheap plastic, and I am aware of no alternatives to them.
